# Remove text and only leave icon under @media(min-width: 768px)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a tab menu that I am presenting on my web page. However, when resizing I am being met with an unexpected behavior, hence my goal is to remove the text and leave only the fa icon when the device is a phone basically @media(min-width:768px).

Here is how the menu is:

```
<div>
          <div class="d-flex flex-row text-white align-items-stretch text-center">
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
              <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i> Home
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resume">
              <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i> Resume
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#portfolio">
              <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> Portfolio
            </div>
            <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i> Contact
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to remove those names Home, Contact, Resume, Portfolio when the device is @media@media(min-width:768px).

This is how my @media query currently looks like:

```
   @media (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-header .port-item {
    width: 25%;
  }

  #main-header .port-item .fa {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .map-responsive {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

Here's a picture of what I am referring to:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to hide the desk on desktop or on mobile? Your question seems inconsistent with the CSS block you have. If you want to hide it on mobile, you should use something like `max-width: 767px` instead of `min-width: 768px`.

Comment: @cjl750 thanks for your time. on the desktop it's working fine I have text and icon, but please see the picture I have attached, it's for the mobile, I would like to remove or hide the text and only leave the icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a span tag around your text, and make it `display: none` in a media query, such as `@media (max-width: 768px)`.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row text-white align-items-stretch text-center">
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home">
      <i class="fa fa-home d-block"></i> <span class="item-label">Home</span>
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resume">
      <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap d-block"></i> <span class="item-label">Resume</span>
    </div>
    <div class="port-item p-4 bg-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#portfolio">
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open d-block"></i> <span class="item-label">Portfolio</span>
     </div>
     <div class="port-item p-4 bg-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#contact">
       <i class="fa fa-envelope d-block"></i> <span class="item-label">Contact</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #main-header .port-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
  #main-header .port-item .fa {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
  .map-responsive {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  #main-header .port-item .item-label {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding HTML to show how it'd look with the span added would make this answer make a lot more sense.

Comment: I wish I can make you richer by now. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Pubith_Jain my approach was to just put the span as you suggested and did this instead #main-header .port-item span {
    display: none;
  }

Comment: @Marie that will work too but it is not a best practice to directly target html elements in CSS that might cause some issue in future while maintaining the project.